# jQuery 1.2.6 -> 1.6 : Possibilities?

Tags: jquery

This seems like such a ridiculous question, but our intranet portal which hosts hundreds of individual modules written by a wide range of developers is still running jQuery 1.2.6.  I would like to upgrade, but I can already tell this is going to be a nightmare, and I can't find any definitive source of the compatibility issues between each version from 1.2.6 to 1.6.

Does anyone have any times, or do I just switch it out and start fixing errors and alerting developers when their modules break?

Edit: What about including two versions of jQuery to try and transition from the older version to the new one?  Perhaps using $ and $$ or something to that affect?  Reading this comments, makes me want to forget the whole thing because there is so much code that I don't support, I just support the portal itself and tell the developers what version of jQuery we are running.

Comment: I had a big issue 1.3-> 1.5, notable with the .live() syntax, and what gets passed into the function and in what order. I ended up sandboxing the old app, and promoting new code with 1.5 (and making updates more regular, to avoid this in the future).

Comment: That's a good question and definitely a very good initiative on your part for willing to upgrade but I am afraid that providing a conclusive answer will be difficult. If you are using jQuery plugins that have dependencies you might need to upgrade those as well. It's a big gap indeed between 1.2 and 1.6. Last time I did this I had a few late night calls for some broken functionality :-) Good luck.

Comment: I can't give you a list but I recently upgraded from 1.3 to 1.6 with minimum issues. I think its worth a try to just upgrade and see how much is broken, you can always reverse it. All public API's should still be intact, what gave me problem was extensions/plugins that needed minor refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, why do you want to upgrade?

Assumedly because you want access to the newer features. Old code won't use those, so why not just use the newer version from now on?

Do you want a performance boost? Do you have code that you know will benefit from the improvement?

Once you have that clear in your mind, just do it, late one night (or ideally on your test server, but question implies you don't have one!) and see what breaks. I'd suspect the only problems will be things that use `attr` that should use `prop` – I've had some issues with older scripts that use the old behaviour of `attr`.

Comment: To add to this, there will also be issues with some selectors due to swapping over to the sizzle engine in 1.3, any 3rd party plugins you are using will need to be updated or replaced, jquery ui will need to be updated, and you may need to re-evaluate some of your selectors for performance since there has been a lot of performance changes between 1.2 and 1.6 ( and soon to be 1.7 )

Comment: The ideal situation is to be able to update on a per-area basis, so that you don't have to re-do the entire application at once.

Comment: Of course we have a test server, but I still have 30+ developers working on projects with timelines so simply switching jquery on them isn't something I can do.  I'm obviously interested in the additional features and the performance improvements.  Without including both version at once, I don't see a way for me to use 1.6 from now on, as the portal includes the jquery not each individual developer.

Comment: I'd do what you say, and include 1.6 as $$ for now, that lets individual devs deal choose what they want. You could always set a deadline if appropriate by which time you will phase out the old version. Sounds like a nightmare!